# HP Stream 7 originally runs Windows - Can it run Android viably?

Tags: boot, tablet, windows, operating-system, dual-boot

I have an HP Stream 7 that I'm not using here (since I've bought my Asus T100), and I was thinking about putting an Android to run, instead of the Windows OS. I know that is possible, but my question is: is it viable? Has someone already tested this using the same model? Does it have any problems with drivers, or something that Android does not recognize? If it works, I'll definitely give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of work, I was able to run an Android live version at the HP Stream 7. Unfortunately, it's a little bit buggy, mainly because there is no drivers available for the device. I will make some researches on, to see what I can find. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Drivers are the largest issue, trying this.  LUbuntu (ubuntu lite) or XUbuntu (runs x11 gui manager, even lighter) BUT, you'll need to know the CPU type on your tablet.  Most all 'nix' software is ported to run on x386 (aka Intel Atom) processor.  The ARM architecture is more of a challenge. NOOBS the standard Raspberry Pi image, gives you a 50/50 chance.!   IMHO  Some of the ARM xuntu distributions would probably run fine.  You'll have to read on those OS and Platforms.  The new Allwinner Tech ARM CPU's are forcing their way into  being the ARM standard. you'll then have to worry about drivers, & not be afraid of downloading and installing APK files... good luck, keep us posted.  I have a couple allwinner white box tablets, that bricked themselves, it would be nice to have them run "something" , even if it's a remote video cam to watch the kid go in/out of the house!

Comment: Maye I can try Live USB the Ubuntu. I tried the Android version at the Stream 7, but I had problems with a couple of things. Screen rotation wasn't working, and also bluetooth, and so on. Maybe it was due to lack of drivers, indeed. But I'll hear you, and try to LiveUSB the LUbuntu on it!

Answer (score -1):

It's months later, I can add a new ponderance to your problem and the solution.
All Android OS on any device is really a Java Virtual Machine.

Download for Linux, Windows, Mac.... the Android SDK  you can build from almost any version, to almost any hardware.  You will have to read, read, read.

Answer (score -1):

no you cant, its just impossible. Drivers are a huge problem as android os needs not available on the stream 7

Comment: Although this answer may be correct, a proper answer should include detailed information and verifiable links to references, otherwise it just sounds like opinion. I suggest reading this page: https://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer to help you improve your answer and future ones.